# is it possible to drop some key-value pairs from logs?

Tags: linux, json, filter, nginx, logstash

I have an nginx log file, that looks similar to this one:

```
{ "@timestamp": "2013-09-03T14:21:51-04:00", "@fields": { "remote_addr": "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "remote_user": "-", "body_bytes_sent": "5", "request_time": "0.000", "status": "200", "request": "POST foo/bar/1 HTTP/1.1", "request_body": "{\x22id\x22: \x22460\x22, \x22source_id\x22: \x221\x22, \x22email_address\x22: \x22foo@bar.com\x22, \x22password\x22: \x2JQ6I\x22}", "request_method": "POST", "request_uri": "foo/bar/1", "http_referrer": "-", "http_user_agent": "Java/1.6.0_27" } }
```

I'm wondering is it possible to use `logstash` filter to send log that would look something similar to this:

```
{"@fields": { "request": "POST foo/bar/1 HTTP/1.1", "request_body": "{\x22id\x22: \x22460\x22, \x22source_id\x22: \x221\x22, \x22email_address\x22: \x22foo@bar.com\x22, \x22password\x22: \x2JQ6I\x22}"}
```

So I'm only interesting in a few fields out of the whole log.

In other words, I would like to extract necessary data out of the log, and than send it to what ever output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that if you first go through a json filter.
Then you need something like this:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    add_tag => "json"
  }
  mutate {
    tags => [ "json" ]
    remove_field => [ "[@fields][remote_addr]", "[@fields][remote_user]", "[@fields][body_bytes_sent]", "[@fields][request_time]" ]
  }
}
```

I've a configuration similar to this working with version 1.2.0 of logstash.
Hope this helps.